# Solving for the Lagrange multiplier

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm reading the guide to gravity equation by Ben Shepherd. The author shows the derivation of Anderson and van Wincoop Gravity Model (2003). I got stuck when trying to understand the following equations:

[image]

I don't understand how Author got to the equation (10). Does he take the integral of the right hand side of the equation (9)? Then I don't understand why

[image]

is considered as a parameter and taken out of the integral.

Comment: it's probably a typo, there is $\int_{v \in V_i^k} [p_i^k(v)]^{1-\sigma_k} dv$ on RHS but he repeat it outside of the integral again. (he probably copied the (9) equation during writing (10) and forgot to remove $[p_i^k(v)]^{1-\sigma_k}$ !)

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes sense now